# Game objects are spawned without the target being scanned

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have multiple game objects as children of ImageTarget.

**Ar camera**
world center mode= first_target
Track device pose checked and positional

As i initiate the **game mode**.

All the objects start to fall(sphere collider and mesh renderer turns off).

As i scan the target the object have already fallen through the plane i had  under them(the plane has a mesh collider on it).

If I the scan the target as soon as I initiate Game mode all goes according to plan, the spheres collide with the plane and stay on top of it.

Is it possible to freeze the Y axis of the objects until the target is scanned and how do i enable extended tracking (Objects pass through the plane as soon as i move the camera away from the target and re-scan the target).

Comment: I assume you are talking about [`RigidBody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) components? Did you try to simply enable [`isKinematic`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) and/or turn off [`useGravity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-useGravity.html) until the scan is done?

Comment: it works fine with useGravity turned off, but how do i know that the target has been scanned.where do i need to implement this code (in which script).

Answer (score 0):

Vuforia has the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` .. the code was hard to find ([source](https://gist.github.com/paulosalvatore/d92e049886dbe46602ce829e9e7edd3e)) but it looks like this

```c#
/*==============================================================================
Copyright (c) 2017 PTC Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Copyright (c) 2010-2014 Qualcomm Connected Experiences, Inc.
All Rights Reserved.
Confidential and Proprietary - Protected under copyright and other laws.
==============================================================================*/

/*
 * Modified by PauloSalvatore on 04/03/2018 - 15:38 (GMT-3)
 *
 * Change Log:
 *
 * Track Events added on Inspector
 * Custom events can be added to be invoked during initialization,
 * when appear start, when object is appearing and when disappear start.
 */

using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Vuforia;

[System.Serializable]
public class TrackEvents
{
    #region PUBLIC_EVENTS

    public UnityEvent onInitialized;
    public UnityEvent onAppear;
    public UnityEvent isAppearing;
    public UnityEvent onDisappear;

    #endregion PUBLIC_EVENTS
}

/// <summary>
///     A custom handler that implements the ITrackableEventHandler interface.
/// </summary>
public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler
{
    #region PUBLIC_EVENTS

    public TrackEvents trackEvents;

    #endregion PUBLIC_EVENTS

    #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    protected TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

    #endregion PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);

        // onInitialized custom events
        if (trackEvents.onInitialized != null)
            trackEvents.onInitialized.Invoke();
    }

    protected virtual void Update()
    {
        // isAppearing custom events
        if (trackEvents.isAppearing != null)
            trackEvents.isAppearing.Invoke();
    }

    #endregion UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    #region PUBLIC_METHODS

    /// <summary>
    ///     Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
    ///     tracking state changes.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
                 newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NOT_FOUND)
        {
            Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
        else
        {
            // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND
            // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet
            // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    #endregion PUBLIC_METHODS

    #region PRIVATE_METHODS

    protected virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // Enable canvas:
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = true;

        // onAppear custom events
        if (trackEvents.onAppear != null)
            trackEvents.onAppear.Invoke();
    }

    protected virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        var rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        var colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);
        var canvasComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Canvas>(true);

        // Disable rendering:
        foreach (var component in rendererComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable colliders:
        foreach (var component in colliderComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // Disable canvas:
        foreach (var component in canvasComponents)
            component.enabled = false;

        // onDisappear custom events
        if (trackEvents.onDisappear != null)
            trackEvents.onDisappear.Invoke();
    }

    #endregion PRIVATE_METHODS
}
```

This should be placed on the according ImageTarget or whatever target you are using by defualt afaik. As you can see they are disabling the `Renderer`, `Collider` etc if the target is lost ... I personally would always remove this and instead replace it by [`UnityEvent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) so I can decide later what should be happening and what not.

Since the two methods `OnTrackingFound()` and `OnTrackingLost()` are `virtual` you can inherit from `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` and override/replace their functionality. By not also calling `base.OnTrackingFound()` or `base.OnTrackingLost()` we are telling c# to **not** execute whatever the parent class originally implemented but to **only** use what we implement:

```c#
// This is used to directly pass a string value into the event
// I'll explain why later ...
[Serializable]
public class VuforiaTargetFoundEvent : UnityEvent<string, Transform> { }

public MyTrackableEventHandler : DefaultTrackableEventHandler
{
    // Give this specific VuforiaTarget a certain custom ID
    // We will pass it dynamically into the UnityEvent
    // so every listener automatically also knows WHICH target
    // was lost or found
    public string TargetID;

    public VuforiaTargetEvent _OnTrackingFound;
    public VuforiaTargetEvent _OnTrackingLost;

    protected override void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        // call _OnTrackingFound with your specific target ID and
        // also pass in the Transform so every listener can know
        // WHICH target was found and WHERE it is positioned
        _OnTrackingFound?
    }

    protected override void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        // call _OnTrackingLost with your specific target ID and
        // also pass in the Transform so every listener can know
        // WHICH target was lost and WHERE it was last positioned
        _OnTrackingLost?
    }
}
```

Simply place this on the Vuforia target instead of the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` (if it was even there already) so now by default none of the `Renderer`,`Collider` etc in children will be disabled. (If you still need it you can ofcourse again add the `base.OnTrackingLost()` and `base.OnTrackingFound()` or alternatively implement it in a separate script and reference the according methods as callbacks in our just newly added `UnityEvents` ;) )

---

Now to your falling objects. At the beginning set `useGravity` to `false` so they don't fall down anymore. Then as a callback once the imagetarget was found enable it.

```c#
public GravityEnabler : MonoBehaviour
{
    // either reference this in the Inspector ...
    public RigidBody _rigidBody;

    // also this either reference it in the Inspector ...
    public MyTrackableEventHandler target;

    // ... or get them on runtime
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!_rigidBody) _rigidBody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
        if(!target= target = FindObjectOfType<MyTrackableEventHandler>();

        // before start disable gravity
        _rigidBody.useGravity = false;

        // setup the callback for the target
        target._OnTrackingFound.AddListener(OnTargetScanned);
        target._OnTrackingLost.AddListener(OnTargetLost);
    }

    privtae void OnDestroy()
    {
        // If this object gets destroyed be sure to remove the callbacks
        // otherwise you would get exceptions because the callbacks
        // would still exist but point to a NULL reference
        target._OnTrackingFound.RemoveListener(OnTargetScanned);
        target._OnTrackingLost.RemoveListener(OnTargetLost);
    }

    public void OnTargetFound(string targetID, Transform targetTransform)
    {
        _rigidBody.useGravity = true;
    }

    public void OnTargetLost(string targetID, Transform targetTransform)
    {
        // If you need to do anything here
        // maybe you want to stop the falling again when the target is lost
        _rigidBody.useGravity = false;
        _rigidBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Place this on every of your faling objects and maybe setup the references already in the Inspector if possible (a bit more efficient).